# Change animation origin on mouse off event

Tags: css

I've got some css/html code. I wanna improve my "unhover" state by doing following: when I hover over a button there is a before element sliding from left to right. I can easily change it from right to left. However when I do the "unhover" action, before element slides in the opposite direction - from right to left. What I want to achieve is animating it's width from 100% to 0% but from left to right. What should I do to get the result?

https://codepen.io/trueFalse24/pen/YzKNgYm

```
a{
    background: #7f8c8d;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;

    &:before{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 0%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(236,240,241, 0.3);
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    &:hover{
      &:before{
        width: 100%;
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your pen to get the effect by changing a few usages of the `left` and `right` properties. My edits are marked by comments below.

```
.container{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #3498db;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;

  a{
    background: #7f8c8d;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;

    &:before{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0; /* Replaced left */
      width: 0%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(236,240,241, 0.3);
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    &:hover{
      &:before{
        width: 100%;
        right: auto;  /* Added */
        left: 0; /* Added */
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can't mark your answer but big thumbs up !